# Is there a formula for "paste speacial as value"

Tags: excel, function

I have a cell in a text format that contains a mathematical formula such as =(1+2+3)/3.

I want to calculate the value of this formula in another cell, but I want to keep the formula. Is there an "excel function" that can do that?

Note: I don't want to do it manually using copy-paste speacial-values (CTRL+C, CTRL+shift+V, values).

I used fucntion VALUE() and it gave back #VALUE

Comment: No, this is not possible with Excel formulas. It is possible with VBA. https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula

Comment: I guess today's the day I am learning VBA... :) thank you!